# Adobe Target and AEM does not work

Tags: adobe, aem, targeting

Targeting does not work on OTB pages.

i created a new activity with adobe target engine, named "test-we-retail"

two audiences named "test-chrome-audience", "test-safari-audience" with rules browser equals to chrome, safari respectively.

I opened up page in preview mode in safari, still see default audience text. " default discover the finest gear"

i should be seeing " test safari discover the finest gear" in text box.

I followed this article https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/AEM-targeting-personal.html , I did not use any experience fragments rather I edited the text for different audience.

Any help ?

Comment: What kind of campaign (activity) are you using - A/B testing or Experience Targeting?

Comment: Experience Targeting